# Getting $5$ in a row of same color card "mystery"

Tags: probability, card-games

I was wondering why this is the case... If you take a standard well shuffled deck of $52$ cards and draw cards randomly without replacement until you get $5$ of the same color (red or black) in a row (or run out of cards), my computer simulation is showing me that the most frequently occurring # of cards drawn when that happens is $5$ cards and it gets worse as more cards are drawn.  Can someone explain why this is?  For example, if I simulate $1$ million hands, it is telling me that $50{,}469$ hands (about $5$%) are "winners" with only $5$ cards drawn but then it drops off sharply at $6$ cards drawn down to only $27{,}826$ winners.  Why is that?  Also somewhat surprisingly (to me), it is telling me that about $2/9$ ($2$ out of every $9$ games) results in no "winner", even with all $52$ cards drawn.

I have the graph output from Wolfram Alpha and want to display it here so how do I embed an image here?

Comment: Starting with "my computer simulation", your question is extremely unclear, and contains several contradictions. First you say that $5$ cards is most frequent number of cards drawn, then you say it is $50,469$, then you say "$6$ cards drawn down to only $27,826$ winners". What on earth does the term "winners" even mean in the context of this question???

Comment: Getting $5$ in a row is considered a "winner".  For example, $5$ red cards or $5$ black cards in a row (consecutive).  I used computer simulation to check this because it is easy but I don't understand why there is that sharp "drop" from $5$ to $6$ cards.  It seems it should be "harder" to get $5$ in a row drawing only $5$ cards rather than $6$ but I am seeing the opposite.  It is "harder" drawing $6$.  I don't see any contradictions in my question which I thought was fairly clearly stated.

Comment: Note that when I say drawing $5$ or $6$ cards I mean exactly that many so I am saying it appears "harder" to get $5$ in a row of the same color drawing exactly $6$ cards then it is drawing exactly $5$ cards.  This is surprising to me.

Comment: Are you cutting off your simulation once you "Win"? Let's just look at the situation with 5 and 6 cards drawn. To win with 5 cards drawn the probability is $2*\frac{26*25*24*23*22}{52*51*50*49*48}$ To win with exactly six card drawn the probability is $2*\frac{26*26*25*24*23*22}{52*51*50*49*48*47}$

Comment: Yes the hand stops as soon as there is a "win" ($5$ in a row) then we start a "fresh" hand.  If someone could please tell me how to plot a graph on here I can show you all the probabilities from $5$ to $52$ cards drawn as well as the no win situation (which is about $22$%).  What is surprising to me is how the percentage drops quickly from $5$ cards to $6$ cards then basically very slowly drops from $6$ to $52$, but it is not a pure "drop" as it fluctuates a little between $6$ and $8$ then goes into a slow drop.  I'll list a few of the winners as tuples out of 1 millions decisions.

Comment: $(5: 50247), (6: 27943), (7:28017), (8: 28443), (9: 27944), (10: 25960), (11:25409), (12:24584), (13: 23930)...(26:15434)...(51:6677), (52:6416)$, no winner: $226149$. Note that since these numbers come from a simulation, they are slightly different each time I run it.  These are out of $1$ million decisions so it is easy to calculate the percentages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the 5/6 card question, note that winning in precisely 5 cards requires the 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th cards to all be the same colour as the first card, while winning in precisely 6 cards requires the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th *and 6th* cards to all be the opposite colour to the first card. Being the opposite colour to the 1st card is slightly more likely than being the same colour, but not enough to cancel out the effect of needing one more card to be the right colour. We can work out these probabilities exactly quite easily:

$P(\text{win in exactly 5 cards}) = \frac{25}{51}\frac{24}{50}\frac{23}{49}\frac{22}{48} \approx 0.0506$

$P(\text{win in exactly 6 cards}) = \frac{26}{51}\frac{25}{50}\frac{24}{49}\frac{23}{48}\frac{22}{47} \approx 0.0280$

On the 52 card no-win question: you have 48 "chances" to win (i.e 48 blocks of 5 cards that could be all the same colour). The above suggests - though I don't have a full proof - that the probability of winning in any specific one is at most $1/20$, and often significantly smaller. If we assume that the probability of winning at any specific chance is $1/20$, then the probability of not winning would be $(19/20)^{48} \approx 0.085$. And this is almost certainly an underestimate - as we've seen above, the probability of winning at the second "chance" is significantly less than $1/20$. This suggests that the probability of not winning  being $2/9$ is not unreasonable.

Comment: Okay I think I get in now.  In the $5$ card scenario it is simpler because the 1st card is a "freebie" meaning we don't really care what it is since we just have to color match the next $4$ cards to it.  In the $6$ card scenario, after the first card is drawn, the next $5$ cards have to mismatch the color of the 1st card which is "harder".  It is also interesting how there is a "peak" at $8$ cards then it starts going back down slowly.  I am sure there is a reason for this.  So how do I plot a graph here so we can see all the contributions of $5,6,7,8$... cards to the winners?

Comment: I tried plotting in Wolfram Alpha but it wouldn't take more than about $29$ datapoints and we need/want many more.  I want to plot here but perhaps this formatting language has a low limit too to the number of data points.  I want to do something like Plot({0,0,0,0,50247,27943...}) so it shows on the graph with $5$ aligning to $50247$, $6$ aligning to $27943$....

Comment: @David If you've got the data and just want to plot the graph, there are all sorts of programs that will do that (Excel will, if nothing else!).

Comment: user73985 - If you had used the $0.0280$ "P(6)" win probability and then taken the not win probability of $0.9720$ then raised that to the 48th power, you would have gotten much closer to the $22.6$% no win estimate for all $52$ cards drawn.  It is still interesting to me how from $5$ cards to $6$ it dips so much then starts to creep back up again but then P(6) is almost identical to P(9).  In the simulation of $1$ million decisions, they only differ by $1$ outcome!  This tells me that mathematically they might have identical probabilities.  That would be interesting to check "on paper".

Comment: @David remarkably, it is true that $P(6) = P(9)$. I won't post the calculation, but it's not *that* hard to do if you want to verify it.

Comment: Wow, I guess my simulation program is "right on the money" then.  I am very tempted to get 1 billion decisions and plot the results to see if P(6) and P(9) come out to identical or extremely close like with only 1 million decisions. I love computer simulation for problems like this because I can get so much information and study the patterns and sometimes they are very surprising. I can create "buckets" for counting up interesting stuff such as what is the average # of cards for "ties" only.  That would likely be a "bear" to compute on paper.  Also I may play 10 rounds of this with real cards.

Comment: -user73985- Actually I would like to see the calculation for $P(6)=P(9)$ since you already confirmed it.   I tried it on paper but ran into some problems.

Comment: @David sorry for not replying earlier. The calculation for $P(6) = P(9)$ is rather messier than I want to try to LaTeX, sorry. The short version goes: $P(9)$ is the sum of 8 possibilities, $SSSDDDDD$, $SDSDDDDD$, etc, where $S = $ same colour as 1st card, $D = $ different colour. Each of these you can work out the probability for in much the same way as we did for $P(6)$. Each of these has numerator $51 \cdots 44$, and the denominators are all divisible by $26 \cdots 22$. So we can write $P(9) = P(6)\cdot \frac{\text{some number}}{46 \cdots 44}$. Then check that number equals $46 \cdots 44$